# Moveuploaded files function in PHP moves the file to the temp directory but not to the destination directory

Tags: php, file-upload

```
 $tmpName = basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
 $rightname = basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $workDir."/".$tmpName) or  die("Cannot move uploaded file to working directory");
 if(!is_writable($_POST['filetype']))
    die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $_POST['filetype'].'/'.$rightname)    or die("Cannot move uploaded file to destination directory");
```

I have a form that uploads a file and posts data to a php script that contains the above code. The above code works partially, as in, the first 'move_uploaded_file' works and the uploaded file gets moved from the var/tmp folder to the $workDir folder. The file has the same name as the one given by the server when it places the uploaded file on the tmp folder with a temporary name before moving it to the destination directory. I feel this works because I am not renaming the temporary name given to the file by server, when it places the file in the tmp folder, after I submit the form. Because the second 'move_uploaded_file()' dies with the error specified. The directory is writable. It is chmoded into '777'. No issues with that. And this is where I am changing the name of the file to what it needs to be. Seems to be a minor issue but I have spent too much time on this without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you called `move_uploaded_file()` you moved that file from temporary folder to `$workDir`. After that, uploaded file no longer exists in temporary directory.

Just use [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function to move that file from `$workDir."/".$tmpName` to final destination.

```
// moves file from workdir to final destination
rename($workDir."/".$tmpName, $_POST['filetype'].'/'.$rightname);
```

Comment: on the other hand i dont see why this two-step approach is needed

Comment: @mnagel Yes. I had it initially for testing and left it as it is. But now I got rid of the extra step and it still works. Thanks :) Interestingly, this started actually as an ftp issue for me. but for the sake of getting the upload feature right I had to abandon the ftp route so I left some portions of the code just as it was.